# How to except words after setting filter parameter logging in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

after setting filter parameter logging in config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb, it filters parameters using Regex pattern.

If I filter "code" as "FILTERED" in log, But I dont want to filter "somecode", How to show "somecode" in log?

Comment: You can't. It's not logged, that's the whole point. The logs are just text, if the string `FILTERED` is written to the log, that's all the data that exists.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your regex includes start/end of string characters - so it exact-matches, instead of partially matching.

eg `/^code$/` instead of just `/code/`

The latter matches any instance of code anywhere in a string... the former matches "code" exactly and will not match "somecode"

Comment: in config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb,     `Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [:password]`, the Regex patterns are built in rails

Comment: I've personally never tried putting in a regex in there... what happens if you do... does it explode?